# How much damage do high energy experiments impose on the LHC detection equipment?

Tags: energy, experimental-physics, large-hadron-collider

I do appreciate that I am second guessing lots of experts who have already considered this aspect of high energy experimentation, but I have not seen a similar question, my apologies if I missed a duplicate.

I know nothing about experimentation or experimental techniques, but I would imagine that some components will need refitting, whilst others may need recalibration rather than a replacement.

What is the expected lifetime of the various detection equipment fitted to the LHC,  obviously in particular the CMS  and ATLAS  detectors?

There are many different components and, if this is a list question, my apologies, I will remove it, but I have learned a lot about particle physics from asking about the experimental side, thus the question.

Comment: There is not a simple answer. Radiation damage had to be taken into account when designing the experiment see this thesis when LHC and CMS were still a gleam in the proposers eyes http://cds.cern.ch/record/308251/files/mika.pdf and this list of radiation damage conferences https://mmoll.web.cern.ch/mmoll/links/conferences.htm

Comment: @annav thanks anna,  if I had seen the second link, I would not have asked the question:). Maybe I will get a general answer, as I have obviously vastly underestimated the initial design work. Regards

Comment: here is an estimate for detector components which should last more than 20 years ( previous experience of collider lifetimes) https://www.google.gr/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&ved=0CDUQFjADahUKEwiMq5fr4rfIAhWCuBQKHQBhDeg&url=https%3A%2F%2Findico.cern.ch%2Fevent%2F67839%2Fsession%2F6%2Fattachments%2F1022442%2F1455509%2FVV_6.docx&usg=AFQjCNHCBVNtPtNqrTd1w35e00a1qP_w7Q